# Where is SourceTree hiding?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I successfully installed SourceTree on a Windows 7 PC today.

After the installation I successfully used SourceTree, closing it when I was done. But now I can't restart SourceTree.  It is not listed in Start/All Programs.  There is no startup icon/link anywhere.  I can see it in Control/Panel "Programs and Features."

This is no trace of SourceTree in Program Files.

There are lots of SourceTree files in AppData/Local/SourceTree, including at least two SourceTree.exe files, but they seem to be installation programs.
I know SourceTree is present.  But where is the main executable?  How can I start it?

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/What-s-the-default-SourceTree-installation-folder-on-Windows-10/qaq-p/265790

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/Installation-folder-on-Windows/qaq-p/88188

Comment: This is in no sense a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @matt Sure it is: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic And 2 years later, this is still a problem with sourcetree, funny.

Comment: @Andrew "and is a practical, answerable problem that is _unique to software development_" There you go. You could ask this same question without doing any software development at all. This is a question about how to use Windows to launch an application. Where an application's main executable is has nothing whatever to do with programming.

Comment: @matt The software in question is only used for software development, and people that use it can't do any development without it (eg clone a repo), and so how to find it is has everything to do with development.

Comment: @Andrew That's not true at all. Any Git user can use SourceTree, and Git is for versioning, not for software development. I've often used Git to version things totally unrelated to software development.

Comment: @matt Anyways it's commonly used by developers, and people ask questions related to software issues all the time. So if you think they should all be deleted, best take it to Meta.

Comment: @Andrew please don't tell me where to take it or make assumptions about what I think. You are entitled to your opinion and I'm entitled to mine. You are the one who stirred this up, from a comment I made over two years ago. If you think the comment is outdated or rude, call for a moderator. Otherwise, it stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Folder you are looking for is in the following directory:

(C:\Users\YourUserName) \AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe

If the above folder is not created then should be a bug, reinstall with the latest version (>=3.1.3, https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

The .exe file is not contained in the folder \AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree